# Wordpress hide some posts on the site

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site. I want to hide some posts on this site everywhere on the site (Homepage, search page, archive, etc.).

I found a code like this;

```
    function exclude_from_everywhere($query) {
   if ( $query->is_home() || $query->is_feed() ||  $query->is_search() || 
$query->is_archive() ) {
     $query->set('post__not_in', array(992, 1968, 173));
   }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_from_everywhere');
```

This code hides the text according to the ID number. However, what I want is to hide according to the custom field section on the site. The code below is the custom field code;

```
get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Mood', true);
```

If something is written in a custom field called Mood, what should I do to hide these topics? In other words, if the custom field is full, the posts should be hidden, but if nothing is written in the custom field, the posts should not be hidden.

Thank you very much in advance to those who help.

Comment: This could be helpful: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/94217/96806

Comment: I just tried this code, but everything on the site is gone. So the menus don't show up. When I add this, I want to hide what is written in the Mood custom field. With this code, the Mood field is full. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$meta_query`

```
function exclude_from_everywhere($query) {
   if ( $query->is_home() || $query->is_feed() ||  $query->is_search() || $query->is_archive() ) {
    $meta_query = array(
               array(
                  'key'=>'Mood',
                  'value'=>true,
                  'compare'=>'=',
               ),
    );
    $query->set('meta_query',$meta_query);
}
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_from_everywhere');
```

Comment: I just tried this code, but everything on the site is gone. So the menus don't show up. When I add this, I want to hide what is written in the Mood custom field. With this code, the Mood field is full. How do I solve this?